# gradle with an exception while running a plugin: Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

### I got such an error

```
Execution failed for task ':business:product:card:iLintCheck'.
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':business:product:card:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.
     The value of this property is derived from:
       - task ':common:base:packageDebugRenderscript' property 'headersDir'
```

### and the stack of errors is here:

```
    The value of this property is derived from:
      - task ':thirdpart:multitype:processDebugManifest' property 'manifestOutputFile'
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.LazyPublishArtifact.getDelegate(LazyPublishArtifact.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.LazyPublishArtifact.getName(LazyPublishArtifact.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.publish.DecoratingPublishArtifact.getName(DecoratingPublishArtifact.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.publish.DecoratingPublishArtifact_Decorated.getName(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.model.DefaultIvyArtifactName.forPublishArtifact(DefaultIvyArtifactName.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.PublishArtifactLocalArtifactMetadata.<init>(PublishArtifactLocalArtifactMetadata.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.addVariant(DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.java:157)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder$1.visitChildVariant(DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultVariant.visit(DefaultVariant.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationPublications.collectVariants(DefaultConfigurationPublications.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.collectVariants(DefaultConfiguration.java:934)
......
```

The magic thing is that when I use jvm remote debug, it will success. While just running, it will error.
The AGP version I used is 4.1, gradle version is 6.5